# Is there any way to understand Visual Studio 2012 hints while writing C++ code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

[image: visual studio editor]

Is there any way to understand the meaning of _Ux, _Dx, _Dt here? This mnemonics tells me nothing about parameters.

Comment: Removing provocative words like balderdash from the question might avoid down votes, and maybe adding some sample code would help

Comment: Try a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) documenting `shared_ptr` instead of relying on intellisense

Comment: This is obvious, but finally guys from Microsoft use this notation for some reason...

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260976(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: @doctorlove What does Hungarian notation have to do with what he's seeing?

Comment: @JamesKanze nothing : I need to be quiet and drink my coffee. Sorry everyone

Comment: `_Ux` is the first template parameter, in your case `string`, `_Dx` is the second (default) template parameter.

Comment: @RogerRowland The OP is aware of that, he wants to understand the naming convention leading to the types and parameter names we see here

Comment: They're abbreviations. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb982026.aspx shows that D stands for deleter, etc.

Comment: @Hulk OP wants to understand MS naming conventions? Well, good luck with that ;-)

Comment: @RogerRowland What is wrong with that? Why do I need hints which I can not understand?

Comment: Seems more like OP is complaining than asking a real question. I already pointed out D probably stands for deleter, and U and P probably stand for Unique Pointer. If Intellisense isn't helpful, you'll have to consult some form of documentation anyway.

Comment: @remyabel This is a real question. I just want to be more comfortable writing code. If this is impossible - I have to know that as well.

Comment: You can always configure the IDE if you are unhappy with it.

Comment: @remyabel That means that there is a way to configure the IDE to get more useful info (in relation to this particular topic) or what?

Comment: Intellisense gets its information from somewhere. Whether it's auto-documentation, or pulling it from MSDN. I don't use Visual Studio so I'm not 100% sure, but you might be able to point it towards a reference site with better variable names.

Answer (score 2):

These "mnemonics" as you call it are nothing but a hint generated by Visual Studio's [IntelliSense](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b.aspx) that is meant to ***help you while writing the code*** (syntax) rather than the meaning (semantics).

If you need more information to help you understand the API and its proper usage, you should rather consult the documentation. In this case it might be [the reference for `std::shared_ptr`'s constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)

Answer (score 2):

This "weird names" thing has (at least partly) to do with [reserved identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier). The programmer (you, me) is *not* allowed to define names like `_Ux` that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (nor names like `__x` or `a__b` that contain adjacent underscores) *anywhere* in his source code. The C++ implementation (Standard Library details, compiler internals...) can thus use this reserved "name space" without fearing *name clashes* with user code.

That's a win-win: the implementation will never define names like `fooBar` or `FOO_BAR` (set aside keywords like `int` and public names like `std`, `printf` or `CHAR_BIT`), so you can safely use these names in your code, and reciprocally you should never define names like `_FooBar`, `__foo_bar` or `FOO__BAR`, so that you won't mess up with the implementation (this is especially true for macros).

As for why they use `_Ux * _Px, _Dx _Dt` and not e.g. `_U * __p, _Deleter __d` (also `_Ty` and not `_T`), well, I guess that it's simply their internal naming conventions.